# Font Package not available playwright

Tags: python, dependencies, playwright, playwright-test

I was just installing my project's dependencies with `python -m playwright install-deps` and using WSL2, in Python but suddenly got this output error:

```
BEWARE: your OS is not officially supported by Playwright; installing dependencies for Ubuntu as a fallback.
Installing dependencies...
Switching to root user to install dependencies...
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libfontconfig1' instead of 'libfontconfig'
Package ttf-ubuntu-font-family is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libicu66 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package ttf-unifont is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  fonts-unifont

Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ttf-unifont' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'ttf-ubuntu-font-family' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libx264-155
E: Unable to locate package libenchant1c2a
E: Package 'libicu66' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libjpeg-turbo8' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libvpx6
E: Unable to locate package libwebp6
Failed to install browser dependencies
Error: Installation process exited with code: 100
```

Here's the screenshot, please help me:
[image]